# Rails Routes. Multiple nested routes with member actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I have the following routes:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :milestones, :comments
end

resources :comments do
    member {post :hide}
end
```

And I want to be able to write something like:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :milestones, 
    resources :comments do 
        member {post :hide}
    end
end
```

But this throws an error.

I have searched the Internet but can't seem to find exactly my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the comma between resources :milestones and resources :comments. Your code should be

```
    resources :projects do
        resources :milestones 
        resources :comments do 
            member {post :hide}
        end
    end
```